# Java weird array behavior

Tags: java, arrays

Why is it that this works:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
```

but this doesn't:

```
int[] array;
array = {1, 2, 3};
```

If I have an array instance variable and I want to initialize it in my constructor surely I don't have to go

```
array = new int[3];
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
array[2] = 3;
```

I feel like I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{...}` construct here is called an array initializer in Java. It is a special shorthand that is only available in certain grammatical constructs:

> #### [JLS 10.6 Array Initializers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.6)
>
> An *array initializer* may be specified in a **declaration**, or as part of an **array creation expression**, creating an array and providing some initial values. [...] An array initializer is written as a comma-separated list of expressions, enclosed by braces `"{"` and `"}"`.

As specified, you can only use this shorthand either in the declaration or in an array creation expression.

```
int[] nums = { 1, 2, 3 };       // declaration

nums = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };   // array creation
```

This is why the following does not compile:

```
// DOES NOT COMPILE!!!
nums = { 1, 2, 3 };

// neither declaration nor array creation,
// array initializer syntax not available
```

Also note that:

- A trailing comma may appear; it will be ignored
- You can *nest* array initializer if the element type you're initializing is itself an array

Here's an example:

```
    int[][] triangle = {
            { 1, },
            { 2, 3, },
            { 4, 5, 6, },
    };
    for (int[] row : triangle) {
        for (int num : row) {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The above prints:

```
1 
2 3 
4 5 6
```

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Nuts and Bolts/Arrays](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
- [`java.util.Arrays`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) - has many array-related utility methods like `equals`, `toString`, etc

Answer (score 13):

The literal syntax i.e. `{}` can only be used when initializing during declaration.

Elsewhere you can do the following instead:

```
int[] array;
array = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
```

Answer (score 4):

The `{}` is syntatic sugar that allows you to fill your array with values upon initialization.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this:

```
array = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
```

I'm not sure why it's necessary to specify the type on the righthand side in one version but not in the other.

Comment: Because it's a special shorthand language construct, Java needs a way to recognise you're using it.

Answer (score 2):

Curly braces {} for initialization can only be used in array declaration statements.
You can use:

```
int[] array = new int[] {1,2,3};  // legal
```

but not:

```
array = {1, 2, 3}; //illegal
```

http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/lang/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

array is a reference. This means that when you write `array int[];` array will be equal to null.
if you want to use it, you need first to allocate the array , by `array = new int[3]`, and now you can fill it by.

```
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 2;
```

Now, java has two syntax sugar for filling array. you can write
`arr int[] = {1,2,3}` or 
`arr int[] = new int[]{1,2,3}`

Java will allocate and fill it behind the scene, but this is possible only on the deceleration.