# Java array of enum values

Tags: java, arrays, enums

Machine is defined as `public enum Machine{...}`

`_machines` is defined as `private Machine[] _machines;`

Don't know why this doesn't work:

```
_machines = {Machine.a, Machine.b};
```

error message:

> **illegal start of expression**

Thank you guys!

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504849/java-weird-array-behavior/3504872#3504872

Comment: You might want to look into an [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You are missing one tiny part of the Array declaration.

```
_machines = new Machine[]{Machine.a, Machine.b};
```

Comment: `Machine.a, Machine.b` can be simplified to `a, b`. The prefix is redundant, because an array of Machine enums can only contain Machine enums.

Comment: @ceving this does not work. Is there something I need to do to make this happen? I do not want to write "Machine" every time.

Comment: @PulkitAgarwal have a look at static imports. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

Comment: Ho do I find not the position of some enum on this array?
_machines.indexOf(Machine.a) doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

This can also be declared empty at first if you give it a size.

```
_machines = new Machine[size];
```

Comment: Note that this is different from OP’s case. This initialises an array with null values, whereas OP is asking about initialising it with predefined non-null values.